Does artificially balancing outcomes in regression lead to poor calibration? If so, how to show the poor calibration?
In "classification" problems, it is common for there to be unbalanced-classes. To combat what appears to be a problem (though I would argue that it usually is not a problem), it is common for practitioners to oversample the minority category, either through synthesizing totally new points (e.g., SMOTE) or through adding/removing points in order to balance the categories.
It is easy to show how this ruins the predictions and leads to them being too high, such as in the simulation below.
library(rms)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 10000

# Simulate data for an imbalanced logistic regssion
#
x <- rnorm(N, -3, 1)
z <- x
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)

# Artificially balance the sample (this might be "ROSE" or something similar)
#
N0 <- table(y)[1]
idx <- which(y == 1)
x0 <- x[y == 0]
x1 <- sample(x[y == 1], N0, replace = T)
x_balanced <- c(x0, x1)
y_balanced <- rep(c(0, 1), c(N0, N0))

# Run the logistic regression on the balanced data and then the original data
#
L_balanced <- glm(y_balanced ~ x_balanced, family = binomial)
L_orig     <- glm(y          ~ x,          family = binomial)

# Predict on the original data according to each logistic regression
#
preds_balanced <- predict(L_balanced, data.frame(x_balanced = x), type = "response")
preds_orig     <- predict(L_orig    , data.frame(x          = x), type = "response")
summary(preds_balanced)
summary(preds_orig)

# Check the calibration of each model: if the predicted probabilities align
# with the reality of event occurrence
#
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
rms::val.prob(preds_balanced, y) # Terrible calibration: predictions are way too high
rms::val.prob(preds_orig,     y) # Good calibration
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))


The plots show the logistic regression on the original data to have good calibration, with all predicted probabilities more-or-less aligning with the reality of event occurrence. On the other hand, the predictions from the balanced model make outrageous claims like a prediction of $0.8$ probability when the event occurrence probability is really more like $0.2$. The ROCAUC is the same for both models, so the lack of calibration does not even lead to better separation of the categories.
For this and other reasons, statistics typically takes a dim view of artificially balancing the data.
That was "classification" with categorical outcomes. What about in regression problems with numerical outcomes, all of which might be different? I suspect there would be similar behavior if skewed outcomes were artificially balanced to make the rare events appear to be routine, leading to a lack of credibility of a large prediction. In the "classification" case, the graph shows that artificial balancing means a prediction like $0.8$ should not be taken seriously, because the true probability is really more like $0.2$. I imagine a regression with artificial balancing giving high predictions with true distributions far away from those high values, so a value predicted to be high might just be "crying wolf," yet I am struggling to show this.
What happens in the regression case? Am I correct that artificially balancing outcomes in regression leads to poor calibration? If so, how to show the poor calibration?
I have become curious about this after reading June 2024's Stocksieker, Pommeret & Charpentier Transactions on Machine Learning Research article, Generalized Oversampling for Learning from Imbalanced datasets and Associated Theory: Application in Regression.

I have become curious about this after reading last month's Stocksieker, Pommeret & Charpentier Transactions on Machine Learning Research article, Generalized Oversampling for Learning from Imbalanced datasets and Associated Theory: Application in Regression.

I'd be curious to hear of a practical application where "imbalanced" regression was actually a problem.  I have a suspicion that most of the problems are likely to be handled by modelling the full predictive distribution (e.g. conditional variance and conditional mean).  At least then you can get a handle on the probability of an extreme value - I don't really see how changing the unconditional density of the data helps (unless you have covariate shift).

@DikranMarsupial I think the point is that rare events happen, whether they are unusual categories or values far away from most of the other values, and investigators want those unlikely events to be conditionally likely. In classification problems, it is easy to catch all instances of the unusual event by always (or often) predicting that unusual event, perhaps at the expense of the specificity or precision/PPV, which means that a claimed/predicted unusual category lacks credibility ("crying wolf"). There must be a generalization to continuous outcomes, right? (Maybe there isn't!)

My suspicion is that it's not much of a problem unless the model is misspecified, with a small fraction of the data coming from a different process than the one modelled.  Oversampling that part of the data could "leverage" the estimates well away from where they "ought" to be.  Since in real life most models are misspecified...

@jbowman But then why is it so problematic in the "classification" example I gave that does have correct specification?

@Dave "and investigators want those unlikely events to be conditionally likely." I think that is the point I am missing, I don't understand why investigators would want that (rather than the unlikely events happening as they are distributed in operational conditions).  I did a few applications a few years ago on predicting high levels of air pollution and extreme rainfall, and the "full predictive distribution" approach worked well with no need to mess with the data.

@Dave even when the problem is correctly specified, ML estimates can still be biased for small samples.  However, for classification, the real issue is usually unequal misclassification costs, which is more easily handled by incorporating them into the training criterion (and the imbalance is essentially irrelevant to the solution), the corresponding issue for regression tasks is less obvious (at least to me).

@DikranMarsupial I mean a situation like this where someone has unusual values that are difficult to predict.

@Dave, that looks like the sort of place where the "full predictive distribution" is helpful.  Most regression models are predicting the conditional mean, so they will tend to miss extreme values simply because they are probably in the conditional tails of the true data generating process.  The best you can do is estimate the conditional probability of observing the extreme value (by integrating the tails of the predictive distribution).  Doing this via regression rather than classification makes better use of the information in the data (especially targets).

@DikranMarsupial I'm thinking of "Predict those rare events better or you're fired," type of situations, predicting stock market crashes or something like that.

Molesting the sample is wrong at face value, and ignores many statistical principles.  You don't need simulations to know that poor calibration will result.  In addition, this topic has been completely dealt with elsewhere on this site.  At the heart of the problem is miscasting many problems as classification problems rather than prediction problems.  See here.

@FrankHarrell This question is explicitly not about classification or even predicting when the observed outcomes are categorical. $//$ I'd love to hear your thoughts on that TMLR paper I referenced in my earlier comment.

@Dave, you are still better off using the "full predictive distribution" regression model to predict the probability of the event and then using the misclassification costs to decide what to tell your boss.  This is one of the cases where I agree with Frank Harrell that you should perform regression and defer the decision process (which is typically a classification task - what actions should I perform).

@DikranMarsupial I'm with you, yet that has not stopped people from synthesizing data, either using something like SMOTE for categorical outcomes or the linked GOLIATH method in more generality. When the outcome is categorical, twisting the data to have a uniform distribution across the outcomes leads to terrible results like I showed in the simulation. What about when the outcome is not categorical yet the investigator applies something like GOLIATH to force a uniform distribution?

@Dave people really shouldn't be using SMOTE!  If you (people in general, definitely not you in particular! ;o) really must generate synthetic data it isn't difficult to come up with a simpler, better algorithm, e.g. sampling from a kernel density estimator fitted to the minority class.  That would be likely to have much better small sample properties!  For regression I still don't understand the problem it solves (that isn't better solved using more traditional statistical approaches).

@DikranMarsupial I haven't tested this, but I would expect any artificial class-balancing technique to ruin the calibration under operational conditions (lack of balance), even if the synthesized points are more realistic than those generated by SMOTE. However, it is straightforward to check that lack of calibration like I did in my R simulation. I am not sure how to check for something similar upon artificially simulating data to get a uniform $y_{train}$ distribution in a regression problem.

@Dave in theory you could correct the probability estimates to compensate for the resampling, so it would work again, IF you used something that didn't introduce new biases, like SMOTE.  I used to think that this might deal with the ML bias for small samples - in theory it could but it is too tricky to get it to work reliably in practice.

I started wondering if the nonlinear link function plays into how the calibration is ruined in a logistic regression. This comes from looking at plots of imbalanced data and thinking that the line through the points is going to be about the same, whether we over-represent rare events or not.
set.seed(2024)
N <- 100
x <- c(
  runif(N, 0, 10),
  runif(N, 10, 100)
)

y_values <- function(x, s = 10){
  y <- 1 + 2*x + rnorm(length(x), 0, s)
  return(y)
}

x_oversampled <- c(
  runif(N, 0, 10),
  runif(9*N, 10, 100)
)

y <- y_values(x)
y_oversampled <- y_values(x_oversampled)

plot(x_oversampled, y_oversampled)
points(x, y, col = 'red')


The line through the original red points is about the same as the line through the oversampled black points, so the predictions would be about the same. I do not see how oversampling would help, but it seems not to hurt, either, at least here.
So I could graph the calibration, I tried a linear probability model that has a linear link function, and then I ran the results through rms::val.prob to graph the calibration before and after over-representing rare events.
library(rms)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 10000

# Simulate data for an imbalanced linear probability model
#
x <- c(runif(N, 0.1, 0.2), runif(N, 0.1, 0.8))
y <- rbinom(length(x), 1, x)

# Artificially balance the sample (this might be "ROSE" or something similar)
#
N0 <- table(y)[1]
idx <- which(y == 1)
x0 <- x[y == 0]
x1 <- sample(x[y == 1], N0, replace = T)
x_balanced <- c(x0, x1)
y_balanced <- rep(c(0, 1), c(N0, N0))

# Run the logistic regression on the balanced data and then the original data
#
L_balanced <- glm(y_balanced ~ x_balanced)#, family = binomial)
L_orig     <- glm(y          ~ x)#,          family = binomial)

# Predict on the original data according to each logistic regression
#
preds_balanced <- predict(L_balanced, data.frame(x_balanced = x), type = "response")
preds_orig     <- predict(L_orig    , data.frame(x          = x), type = "response")
summary(preds_balanced)
summary(preds_orig)

# Check the calibration of each model: if the predicted probabilities align
# with the reality of event occurrence
#
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
rms::val.prob(preds_balanced, y) # Terrible calibration: predictions are way too high
rms::val.prob(preds_orig,     y) # Good calibration
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

The calibration plots look about the same as in the logistic regression simulation in the question.

I still want to see an example with a truly continuous outcome that has poor calibration upon oversampling tail events. However, this example with a linear probability model does have me thinking that over-representing rare events, such as what is done in that Stocksieker, Pommeret & Charpentier GOLIATH paper mentioned in the question, can lead to poor calibration, whether the link function is nonlinear or linear.

Sure, linear probability models have their problems, but they do allow for (purported) probability predictions without introducing nonlinearity, which allowed for an easy study of calibation without a nonlinear link function.

I think: for regression the equivalent to the poor calibration due to arbitrary upsampling is equivalent to arbitrary upsampling regions/points with high leverage. Both will introduce arbitrary bias (in case of classification bias for one class)
Upon request I came up with the following example:

On the left you see the samples in blue to which I added a high leverage point (in red, below you also see the high cook distance of this red point)

Next I resampled the data (and also upsampled the high leverage point) this upsampling/increased weight of the high leverage point resulted in worse estimates of the regression coefficient (ground truth 3 and the orange histogram is further away from the ground truth than not performing upsampling but still taking into account the high leverage point (red line)).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.utils import resample

# Set random seed for reproducibility
#np.random.seed(42)

ground_truth_coefficient=3
# 1. Create a synthetic dataset
n_samples = 50
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, 1) * 10
y = ground_truth_coefficient * X.flatten() + np.random.randn(n_samples) * 2

# 2. Add a point with high leverage
x_l=20
X_high_leverage = np.array([[x_l]])  # High leverage point
y_high_leverage = np.array([x_l*ground_truth_coefficient+np.random.randn(1)[0] * 2+10]) #artificially add this high leverage point (which may occur very rarely by sampling from the generating process)

# Original dataset with the high leverage point added
X_with_leverage = np.vstack([X, X_high_leverage])
y_with_leverage = np.hstack([y, y_high_leverage])

# 3. Fit linear regression to the original dataset
model_original = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

# Fit linear regression to the dataset with the high leverage point added
model_with_leverage = LinearRegression().fit(X_with_leverage, y_with_leverage)

# 4. Upsample the high leverage point
num_upsampling_leverage_point = 1000
X_upsampled = np.vstack([X_with_leverage] + [X_high_leverage] * num_upsampling_leverage_point)
y_upsampled = np.hstack([y_with_leverage] + [y_high_leverage] * num_upsampling_leverage_point)

# 5. Bootstrapping
n_bootstrap_samples = 1000
bootstrap_preds = []

for _ in range(n_bootstrap_samples):
    X_bootstrap, y_bootstrap = resample(X_upsampled, y_upsampled)
    model_bootstrap = LinearRegression().fit(X_bootstrap, y_bootstrap)
    bootstrap_preds.append(model_bootstrap.coef_[0])

# Convert bootstrap predictions to a numpy array
bootstrap_preds = np.array(bootstrap_preds)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

# Plot the original data and the data with the high leverage point
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.scatter(X, y, label='Original Data')
plt.scatter(X_high_leverage, y_high_leverage, color='red', label='High Leverage Point')
plt.plot(X, model_original.predict(X), color='blue', label='Original Model')
plt.plot(X, model_with_leverage.predict(X), color='red', label='Model with High Leverage (no upsampling)')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Effect of High Leverage Point on Linear Regression')

# Plot the distribution of the bootstrap coefficients
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.histplot(bootstrap_preds, kde=True, label="Boostraped coef, from models built with 100x upsampled leverage point", color="orange")
plt.axvline(x=model_original.coef_[0], color='blue', linestyle='--', label='Original Coef')
plt.axvline(x=ground_truth_coefficient, color='black', linestyle='--', label='Ground truth Coef')
plt.axvline(x=model_with_leverage.coef_[0], color='red', linestyle='--', label='coef for model built with data containing 1 lverage point (no upsampling)')
plt.xlabel('Coefficient')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Bootstrap Distribution of Coefficient After Upsampling')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Print summary statistics
print(f"Original Coefficient: {model_original.coef_[0]:.4f}")
print(f"Coefficient with High Leverage Point: {model_with_leverage.coef_[0]:.4f}")
print(f"Mean Bootstrap Coefficient (after upsampling): {np.mean(bootstrap_preds):.4f}")


#check if the last point indeed has a high leverage (cook distance)
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(y_with_leverage, X_with_leverage).fit() 

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

#create instance of influence
influence = model.get_influence()

#obtain Cook's distance for each observation
cooks = influence.cooks_distance

#display Cook's distances
#print(cooks) #first cooks distance, second pvalues

plt.scatter(X_with_leverage, cooks[0])
plt.axhline(4/len(X_with_leverage), label="above this line is considered high cook distance", c="red")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("cook distance")
plt.legend()

PS: the direct connection is, that upsampling/downsampling in classification settings biases the probability estimate for finding that class
''Conclusion'': regarding your question "Does artificially balancing outcomes in regression lead to poor calibration? If so, how to show the poor calibration?"
Yes: you the equivalent to poor calibration in classification (=biased probability estimates) is biased regression coefficients. You can simulate obtaining worse regression coefficients (see above) when upsampling high leverage points (higher distance to ground truth regression coefficient). If this biased estimation is or is not a problem for your business problem, or even is beneficial is a totally different question (like in classification, where you might argue that poor calibration is fine if you optimized for cost).

I'm quite confused about how the example relates to my question. It does not seem that it ever considers the predictions and how they correspond to the true values. Could you please clarify?

Well we even know the generating process Y=3X +epsilon where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4)$. When the coefficient around 3 is not estimated in an unbiased fashion (but biased like in the orange histogram of the upsampling of a high leverage point), then it is clear that the predictions tend to not agree with the generating process (i.e. be suboptimal), we could investigate this further in a simulation but it should be clear ...

Biased estimators are used all the time. Ridge, LASSO, and elastic net estimation of linear models are biased. The common estimator of standard deviation, $s = \sqrt{\frac{\overset{N}{\underset{i = 1}{\sum}} \left(X_i - \bar X\right)^2}{n - 1}}$, is biased. Maximum likelihood estimation usually gives biased estimates of GLM coefficients (including logistic regressions that can give perfectly fine calibration of predicted probabilities like in the posted example). I don't see the issue of having a biased estimator when we use them all the time.

Well but unbiasedness in general is a good argument - and I won't list the arguments why it is desirable. In classification settings you can achieve points on a Pareto front by upsampling (or alternative more direct methods like e.g. threshold tuning). In the regression setting it might be the same: you have a multi-objective optimization problem (being good in predicting at points x_1, x_2,... or even certain intervals). Now upsampling might bring you closer to predicting better in a certain interval but it comes at the cost of being biased and potentially having wronger estimates elsewhere

This aspect is shared between classification and regression. You can make the same argument in classification where you could argue that you are not interested in calibration but a certain precision-recall tradeoff for achieving cost optimality ...

The usual MLE for logistic regression is biased. Why does bias of the regression coefficients mean a lack of calibration of the predictions when that doesn't have to be true for logistic regression? You might be interested in posting an answer here.

Well ok, I think being asymptotically unbiased is the desired thing. Obviously for upsampling strategies you would increase the amount of upsampling by a factor of n, if your "normal" samples grew by a factor of n. So this upsampling strategy would be asymptotically biased

Consistency is a nice property of MLEs, sure, but they’re still biased in the finite samples used empirically. I really struggle to understand how this addresses my question.
